# Illustrator, Save for Web: keeping Art and Type optimization separate in one go?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, optimization, save

When exporting for web in Illustrator, there's the ever familiar `Art Optimized` and `Type Optimized` rendition schemes (apart from `None`).

Both schemes have their own perks on different types of elements. Unsurprisingly, Art Optimized excels for anything *but* text, whereas Type Optimized is often a lot better at rendering text/fonts. (Well, I guess that could be a subjective topic, but it's irrelevant to the discussion – let's just stay true to the fact; sometimes you prefer one or the other, and often (here's the gist of the whole thing) you prefer both schemes treating their intended elements, respectively, right?

I often have to export two versions; one *_art_opt.png and one *_type_opt.png when making e.g. a logotype. Then, I have to place both rendered images on two layers in Photoshop, cutting off the Art Optimized portion from the Type area, and vice versa. Just in order to get what I was looking for in the first place: OPTIMIZED art … in other words, "art" rendered Art Optimized and text rendered Type Optimized.

Factor in that I often make various different sizes; transparent versions and opaque versions; saved in various formats … and you have some SERIOUS™ time waste right there.

#### And so, the question

I just wonder, is there any method of having art elements treated with Art Optimized rendition and text elements treated as Type Optimized – all in the same go?

Below is an example showing how the logo mark appears good in one optimization (art) and the logo text appears better in the other optimization (type), in which I'd have to save two files and bring them into Photoshop to manually mix the good parts together :

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When applying anti-aliasing in the `Save for Web & Devices` panel the entire export gets the same anti-aliasing method but you can apply the anti-alisaing on an object level.

Select an object and go to `Effect > Rasterize...`. Choose your desired ppi, it is better to always choose `Use Document Raster Effects Resolution` because then it will be easy to switch all your objects from 72ppi to 300ppi for example by clicking on `Effect > Document Raster Effects Settings...`. Select the anti-aliasing method you want to apply to your object. I always apply `Type Optimized` on text objects but you don't need to do anything on graphics. The only time I use `Art Optimized` is on linked PSD pictures, you get a better result especially if you downscaled the picture in Ilustrator

Another advantage of this method is that what you see on your artboard (once all rasterize filters are applied) will be exactly what you will get when exporting so you can really control the final output.

The object will be rasterized but as it is an effect you can turn it on/off in the `Appareance` panel – so it isn't really rasterized and doesn't get altered. Then when exporting, don't apply any anti-aliasing in the `Save for Web & Devices` panel.

Comment: dlmth: This is bloody brilliant. I can't say how thankful I am for this answer. A note of caution for those who run into the same confusion-gap as I did: If your output is intended for computer screen, change Effects > Document Raster Effects Settings… to 'Screen (72 ppi). Mine was at 'High (300 ppi)', which really messed up the anti-aliasing when Saving for Web.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly... I copy/paste to Photoshop as a Smart Object and Save for Web with Photoshop in these instances. AI's SFW anti-aliasing isn't stunning when the objects are mixed.

Comment: This is interesting! Never thought of that. Seems Photoshop treats the text just a tad better (while maintaining the integrity of the art). However I experienced a nasty color glitch in PS' Save for Web, but I think that has something to do with the fact that the logo I'm currently working on (not the dummy icon above ;) has some pretty elaborate (multiple) opacity masks and inner glow + drop shadow effects going on, which Photoshop doesn't handle the same way.

Comment: I don't use effect on logos. I design flat shapes for logos. However, for better support be certain your AI document color mode is RGB, then copy/paste to Photoshop.

Comment: Great point about color mode consistency, Scott. I was going to ask if you'd care to briefly elaborate on why you're not using effects in logos, but since this is another topic, I'll open a new question thread for it: 

http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5306/mainly-illustrator-what-are-the-technical-negatives-of-using-effects-and-non

Comment: All canned effects do nothing more than "cheapen" the brand. A solid logo shouldn't need any drop shadows or glows or any of that other stuff. Just my opinion. I have absolutely been known to be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

What I've done after reading this was create any text into outlines.

Box select "logo Text" Right click and say "Create Outlines" or `Edit > Object > create outlines`.

This will allow any

Export optimized for Art.

However I was using this for a logo that will be printed, and not just web use. However I imagine it will be much of the same.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, same as above, but for AI 2017:

Select type (w/pointer, not text tool) 
Type> Create outlines.
Voila. Your text is Art, and can now be Art Optimized. Perfect!

Comment: Don't write "same as above" because answers change position due to upvotes / downvotes. Instead if you want to reference another answer say "as @user said". Also what you wrote is more like a comment than an answer to the question.